# Adding custom blocks to the Quick insert block menu in Simulink

Tags: matlab

As of now we can access only Simulink library blocks by Quick Block Insert which allows you to double-click in the canvas background and type block names to insert them. It is significantly faster than dragging blocks from the Simulink Library Browser.

is there a way to add custom blocks to the quick insert block menu with out adding custom library to the Simulink library browser?

is it possible to access custom blocks which are in custom libraries using Quick Block Insert like the way how we can access simulink library blocks?
[text](https://in.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/customizing-the-library-browser.html#br1caqo)

Answer (score 0):

You MUST add your custom library containing your custom block to simulink libraries to use quick insert (and also drag and drop from library browser actually). To do so refer to [here](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/adding-libraries-to-the-library-browser.html)

If you dont want to add your library to simulink there is no alternative ways as far as i know.

Comment: yeah thanks @Ferro Luca for taking your time and answering my question.